# How can I make Ubuntu Dock narrower?

Tags: settings, ubuntu-dock, dock

How can I make Ubuntu Dock smaller? I want to narrow it horizontally (i.e. I want to reduce the size of the icons and make it take up less space).

Comment: I replaced the default Dock with Docky and it's fully customizable. https://askubuntu.com/questions/50522/replacing-unity-bar-with-docky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### GUI option:

Open *Settings* and navigate to the "*Dock*" section (or the ["*Appearance*" section in later releases](https://askubuntu.com/a/1249860/480481)). You'll see a slider to control the size of icons in the dock.

[image]
([screenshot source](https://didrocks.fr/2017/09/08/ubuntu-gnome-shell-in-artful-day-10/))

#### CLI option:

Launch a Terminal window and run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size <VALUE>
```

for example

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dash-max-icon-size 24
```

Comment: This does not work in 20.04

Comment: @roel What *exactly* doesn't work? The GUI option is still there, but it's now moved into the '*Appearance*' section of *Settings*. The CLI option still works as well. Please be specific.

Comment: @RoelVandePaar I just noticed you posted an answer suggesting *dconf Editor* to set the icon size to something less than 16 (lower limit in the GUI option). In case you're unaware `dconf` is a low-level configuration system whose main purpose is to provide a backend to `gsettings`. So the `gsettings` command here achieves the same goal as the `dconf` alternative (notice the `gsettings` schema id is analogous to the `dconf` schema path), which I confirmed in my 20.04 setup. If it doesn't work for you, then most likely you're doing something wrong and/or `gsettings` is broken in your system.

Comment: @pomsky agreed... but, a "backend"... or a front-end?????

Comment: @WU-TANG I don't see where the problem is with what I wrote. The main purpose of `dconf` (*not* the 'dconf Editor' application which is just a GUI editor for `dconf`) is to provide a backend to `gsettings`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf

Comment: I had tried the `gsettings` command and it did not work for me. Using dconf did. Thanks for testing on your end also.

Answer (score 0):

In the gui, at least in 20.04, it will not let you set it smaller then 16. I needed it to be smaller. With thanks to another answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1249861/682596) this is possible;

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

Browse to:

```
org / gnome / shell / extensions / dash-to-dock / dash-max-icon-size
```

Then change custom value as required:
[image: dconf-editor screenshot]