# How can I change the Dock settings in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, system-settings, ubuntu-dock, gnome-control-center

Are the dock settings completely gone from the latest version of Ubuntu? I can't seem to find them in the *Settings* application. If so, how can I change the icon size and move the dock around?

Comment: To move the dock around simply go to settings > appearance > dock and change the "position on screen" setting. In the same screen, you can set the icon size, but the minimum will be 16. To set it to a smaller size then 16, use dconf-editor showcased in @ivan-banha his answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot find the setting, you can try to install dconf editor and change dock's config there.

To install dconf editor run the command below

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open it and go to dash to dock extension

```
org/gnome/shell/extension/dash-to-dock/
```

There you can find all settings

[image: Open the image to see an example]

Comment: just a reminder, in my case I had to reboot

Answer (score 4):

It can now be found in ***Settings*** -->> ***Appearance*** -->> ***Dock***

[image]